# Chart.Js how to hide datapoints with "0" value in Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

I want to hide some bars that dont have a useful value ("0") but I am not sure about how to do it, since I cannot use any Chart.Js plugins and I cannot just hide the whole Dataset since I am using a SQL Table to get the Values "into" Chart.Js.

[I would like to hide the 0-Values on the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6sjB.png)

Note: I only want to hide the Value not the whole bar itself.

````
    //coloring the bars from light blue (receiverColor) to dark blue (performancePayColor)
    var receiverColor = "#7ec0ee";
    var timeWageColor = "#368DD6";
    var performancePayColor = "#214B7D";

    //removing of chart when openening a new OE
    // var chartContainer = document.getElementById('chartContainer');
    // chartContainer.innerHTML = "";

    for (var x = 0; x < charts.length; x++) {
        var chartData = charts[x];

        var sumChartValues = [];

        //adding up the Arrays
        for (var i = 0; i < chartData.GE.length; i++) {
            sumChartValues.push(chartData.GE[i] + chartData.LL[i] + chartData.ZL[i]);
        }

        //creating a TempChart canvas with same values as chart1 to be able to delete Chart1 canvas
        var chart = document.createElement("canvas");
        chart.id = "Chart" + x;

        //make the Charts responsive
        var width = $(window).width(); 
        var paddingL; //= 0;
        var paddingR; //= 0;

        if (width >= 2560) {
           // chart.height = height / 2.2;
            chart.width = width / 2.2;
            paddingL = 25;
            paddingR = 25;
        }
            else if (width >= 1440) {
               // chart.height = height / 2.2;
                chart.width = width / 2.2;
                paddingL = 25;
                paddingR = 25;
            }

            else if (width >= 1024) {
               // chart.height = height / 2.2;
                chart.width = width / 2.5;
                paddingL = 20;
                paddingR = 20;
            }

            else if (width >= 768) {
               // chart.height = height / 2;
                chart.width = width / 1.25;
                paddingL = 30;
                paddingR = 30;
            }

            else {
                //chart.height = height;
                chart.width = width / 1.25;
            } 
        
        document.getElementById("chartContainer").appendChild(chart);

        //var originalOnClick = Chart.defaults.global.legend.onClick;

        new Chart("Chart" + x, {
            //barchart is what we use normally, change type if something else is needed.
            type: "bar",

            data: {
                //labels is for the Values of the first x-Axis (we normally use KW)
                labels: chartData.KW,

                //datasets are the Bars that are displayed on the charts (each Dataset is one different Bar part a.e. a different color and value on one bar and KW)
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Leistungslohn",
                        backgroundColor: performancePayColor,
                        data: chartData.LL,
                        xAxesID: "lowerXAxis",
                    },

                    {
                        label: "Zeitlohn",
                        backgroundColor: timeWageColor,
                        data: chartData.ZL,
                        xAxesID: "lowerXAxis"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Gehaltsempfänger",
                        backgroundColor: receiverColor,
                        data: chartData.GE,
                        xAxesID: "lowerXAxis"
                    }]
            },
            options: {
                //Set the Chart responsive
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                responsive: false,

                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        left: paddingL,
                        right: paddingR
                    }
                },

                //Dynamic Chart title display on top of the Legend
                title: {
                    size: '200',
                    display: true,
                    text: chartData.O_Long[0] + ' (' + chartData.O_Short[0] + ')',
                },
                //Enables legend Over the bars (Leistungslohn, Zeitlohn and Gehaltsempfänger)
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                //Enables tooltips when hovering over bars
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: true
                },

                hover: {
                    //disables number flickering when moving mouse across bars
                    animationDuration: 0,
                    //disables hover effect (change of bar color when hovering over a bar)
                    mode: null
                },

                animation: {
                    //duration = build up time for the chart in ms, 0 = no visible animation.
                    duration: 0,
                    onComplete: function () {
                        //Shows bar values on top of each bar and Formats them
                        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                        var legendItems = this.chart.legend.legendItems;
                        var max = this.chart.scales['y-axis-0'].max;
                        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'bold', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                        //coloring the values white
                        ctx.fillStyle = this.chart.config.options.defaultFontColor = "#FFF";
                        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

                        //Calculation of the required scale
                        var chartHeight = this.height;
                        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                            var index = -1;
                            for (var i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i++) {
                                if (legendItems[i].text == dataset.label && !legendItems[i].hidden) {
                                    index = i;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (index != -1) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                                    var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                                    ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y + (dataset.data[i] / max * ((chartHeight / 2) - 50)));
                                }
                            }
                        })

                        //hide zero values

                    },
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        //Stacks mutliple Datasets on top of each other
                        ID: "lowerXAxis",
                        stacked: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            //removes x-Axes grid lines
                            display: false
                        }
                    },
                    //Second x-Axes:
                    {
                        ID: "upperXAxis",
                        position: "top",
                        offset: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            //removes x-Axes grid lines
                            display: false
                        }
                    }],

                    yAxes: [{
                        //Stacks mutliple Datasets on top of each other
                        stacked: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            offset: true,
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Anzahl Personen',
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            //Makes the chart start at 0 to prevent negative values and to prevent formatting errors
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `options.animation.onComplete` callback function, you draw the text using [`ctx.fillText(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText). Simply don't draw the text in case the value is zero.

To do so, you should add an `if` statement as follows:

```
if (dataset.data[i] > 0) {
  ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y + (dataset.data[i] / max * ((chartHeight / 2) - 50)));
}
```

> In case the values are defined as strings as your question could suggest, the `if` statement may have to be changed slightly (i.e `if (dataset.data[i] != '0') {`).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me (using *ChartJS version 4.2*):

1. Prerequisites: OP says he cannot use **plugins,** so step 3 of this solution would need to be modified if that is still the case - however if you can use the newly separated label plugins for version 4.0 and higher of ChartJS, the below will work *(but you have to import the below plugin CDN below your ChartJS import)*. Use of this plugin is now the officially supported means of displaying labels on top of charts for v4 and above of ChartJS.

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
```

2. First define a set of formatter functions (I have 4 such functions: one simply returns the value as the label, another returns the value formatted as a percentage; **the other two do the same, but return null when the value is equal to 0.** We use these for chart types with **touching** data regions (e.g. stacked bars, pies and donuts).

```js
const absoluteFormatter = (value) => {
    return value;
}
const percentageFormatter = (value) => {
    return Math.round(value) + '%';
}
const absoluteFormatterTouching = (value) => {
    if (value > 0) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
const percentageFormatterTouching = (value) => {
    if (value > 0) {
        return Math.round(value) + '%';
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note the above formatters won't work if you deal with any negative values or string values, so you'd need to adjust them accordingly in that case.

3. Then when working with **plugins**, we use a config file like the below for a stacked bar chart:

```js
const absoluteFormatterTouching = (value) => {
  if (value > 0) {
      return value;
  } else {
      return null;
  }
}

const labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'];
const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [0,4,5,2,10,20,30],
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: [12,19,3,0,2,3,10],
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 3',
            data: [11,20,30,4,51,60,0],
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
        },
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: "bar",
    data: data,
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked",
            },
            datalabels: {
                display: true,
                formatter: absoluteFormatterTouching,
            },
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true,
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true,
            },
        },
    },
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Note the inclusion of the relevant formatter within the chart *config.options.plugins.datalabels.formatter: absoluteFormatterTouching*. This is where you place a pointer to the formatter you wish to use. You also have to include the line *config.plugins: [ChartDataLabels]* to have access to the imported DataLabels plugin from the CDN.